# Multicols moving the text unproperly

Tags: multicol

A problem with multicols. The a_{21} "wanders" to the next column. You can see the code below:

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
$\begin{array}{|ccc|}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
\end{array}$
\columnbreak
$a_{11}$\\
$a_{21}$\\
$a_{31}$\\
\columnbreak
$a_{12}$\\
$a_{22}$\\
$a_{32}$\\
\end{multicols}
```

`

Comment: It is helpful if you post a complete example people can compile as-is rather than just a fragment since it makes it easier to help and takes the guesswork out of it, to some extent, saving people wasted effort and helping you to get genuinely useful solutions.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: we can not "see" anything from the code you post as it does not run on its own and the column breaking depends on the page size, fonts and several other details that you have not shown. Please fix the example so it reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but you should almost certainly look at the environments provided by **amsmath**. **multicol** is really designed for cases where you don't want to specify the breaks but want TeX to figure out how to balance the columns without manual intervention. Where you have continuous text to set in multiple columns and want different numbers of columns on the same page, **multicol** is useful. But where you have `tabular` or `array` material etc., it isn't really the best choice: it isn't needed and so you get all the downsides with none of the benefits. It's a lose-lose situation.

Possibly something like the following might be better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{vmatrix}
    a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
    a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
    a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\\
  \end{vmatrix}
  \qquad
  \begin{matrix}
    a_{11}\\
    a_{21}\\
    a_{31}\\
  \end{matrix}
  \qquad
  \begin{matrix}
    a_{12}\\
    a_{22}\\
    a_{32}\\
  \end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: matrices]